# How can I extract exact key and its values from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, key-value

I have a list of words that should match some of the keys in the a dictionary. How can I return the matching keys an their values?

```
terms = ['history', 'patient', 'anotherTerm', ...]


dictionary = {'history': ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'], 
               'clinical': ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'],
               'patient': ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'], ....}
```

I did this loop that prints the matching keys, but I'm not sure how to print the key's values as well. How can I make sure to return the key and its list of values?

```py
for c in terms:
        for k in concepts.keys():
            if c == k:
                print("key:", k)  #value?
```

Comment: `if term in concepts: ...`

Answer (score 1):

If the list of keys match exactly with the actual keys of the dictionary, you can just use it as the key. I.e., in your example,

`dictionary[terms[0]]` should produce `['str1', 'str2' ...]`. To get the values of a dictionary matching keys from your list, you would just do

```
for c in terms:
    print("key: ", c)
    print("value: ", dictionary[c])
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is built for fast lookups by key. Looping through the keys is inefficient.

Try this instead. It gets the values by key.

```
for c in terms:
     print("key:", k)  
     print("value:", concepts[k]
```